# Invalid bearer token

Tags: c#, azure, authentication

I have two methods. One gets and returns an access token based on an Azure ClientID and Azure Secret Key for the app I have registered. The second then makes a call to an Azure Function, however the function returns an error:

> [9/26/2019 12:18:49 PM] Creating a new Team.
>
> [9/26/2019 12:19:00 PM] Executed 'AddTeam' (Failed, Id=aaecc7fa-e3bd-40e7-8be9-a
>   8a173cc166b)
>
> [9/26/2019 12:19:00 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing functi
>   on: AddTeam. System.Net.Http: The format of value 'Bearer ' is invalid.

Any help gratefully received as it's driving me nuts!

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
{
    string clientId = "clientIDFromAzure";
    string clientKey = "secretKeyFromAzure";

    string authContextURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tennantID";
    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
    var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientKey);
    var result = await authenticationContext
            .AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential);
    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the token");
    }
    string token = result.AccessToken;
    return token;
}

public static async Task<string> CallGraph(HttpMethod method, string uri, string body)
{

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    string graphEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, graphEndpoint + uri);
    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    string accessToken = await TokenHelper.GetAccessToken();

    request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer ", accessToken);

    if (method != HttpMethod.Get)
        request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "applciation/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        throw new Exception(responseBody);
    return responseBody;
}
```

Comment: `"Bearer "` should not have a space. It should be just `"Bearer"`. Let me know if that fixes the issue.

Comment: You've also misspelled `"applciation/json"`, it should be `"application/json"`

Answer (score 0):

In the `GetAccessToken` method, you are trying to get an access token for Azure management API.

```
var result = await authenticationContext
            .AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential);
```

However, you actually use that token to call Microsoft Graph API.  That is why you get the authentication error.

To solve this:

1. You need to add necessary Graph API permissions in your app registered in Azure AD, and then grant consent for those permissions.

[image]

2. Modify your code to acquire token for Microsoft Graph API.

```
var result = await authenticationContext
            .AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/", credential);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the space after Bearer is a true space character (0x20) and not a Unicode equivalent such as non-breaking space (0xa0). I had this problem when copy/pasting between Visual Studio Code, OneNote and PowerShell.

Beware that some scripting languages such as PowerShell treat these characters as equal in default string comparisons:

```
'Bearer ' | Format-Hex # View as hex 

"`u{20}" -eq "`u{a0}"  # True: space == non-breaking space
```